# Sequelize - Can't limit properly query with includes, using hasMany and belongsToMany associations

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

**Issue explanation**

I want to do a query with pagination that limits to 12 lines each query, to be more specific, that limits to 12 `Batches` each query. Actually the amount of lines get smaller because a `belongsToMany` association with a join table i got in this query. The join order to this query is: `Offer` > hasMany > `Batch` > belongsToMany > `BatchFile` > belongsTo > `File`. The problem is, when i have many registries in the `File as 'gallery'` association, it brings me duplicated registries of batch.

**The query i'm trying to do**

```js
const { id } = req.params;
const { page = 1 } = req.query;

const offer = await Offer.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: [ 'id', 'name', 'canceled_at'],
  where: { id, canceled_at: null },
  order: [['offer_batches', 'name', 'ASC']],
  include: [
    {
      /* hasMany association */
      model: Batch,
      as: 'offer_batches',
      attributes: [ 'id', 'name'],
      include: [
        { /* Other includes... */ },
        {
          /* belongsToMany association */
          model: File,
          as: 'gallery',
          attributes: ['id', 'path', 'url'],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  subQuery: false,
  limit: 12,
  offset: (page - 1) * 12,
});
```

**Model associations**

Offer model

```js
this.hasMany(Batch, { foreignKey: 'offer_id', as: 'offer_batches' });
```

Batch model

```js
this.belongsToMany(File, { through: models.BatchFile, as: 'gallery' });
```

BatchFile model (join table)

```js
this.belongsTo(Batch, { foreignKey: 'batch_id', as: 'batch' });
this.belongsTo(File, { foreignKey: 'file_id', as: 'file' });
```

**What i already tried**

Giving `duplicating: false` option to any included Model doesn't worked;

Giving `separate: true` to the `Batch` model doesn't worked too;

Giving `required: true` option to any included model doesn't worked too;

If i remove `subQuery: false` it doesn't respect the setted limit of lines, and i already tried with all of the above combinations;

I thought sequelize would deal with this situation without problems, maybe i'm doint something wrong.

If helps, here's the raw generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT
"Offer"."id",
"Offer"."name",
"Offer"."canceled_at",
"offer_batches"."id"
AS "offer_batches.id", "offer_batches"."name"
AS "offer_batches.name", "offer_batches->gallery"."id"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.id", "offer_batches->gallery"."path"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.path", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."created_at"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.createdAt", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."updated_at"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.updatedAt", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."file_id"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.FileId", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."batch_id"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.BatchId", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."batch_id"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.batch_id", "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."file_id"
AS "offer_batches.gallery.BatchFile.file_id"
FROM "offer" AS "Offer"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "batch" AS "offer_batches" ON "Offer"."id" = "offer_batches"."offer_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  "batch_file" AS "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"
  INNER JOIN "file" AS "offer_batches->gallery"
  ON "offer_batches->gallery"."id" = "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."file_id"
)
ON "offer_batches"."id" = "offer_batches->gallery->BatchFile"."batch_id"
WHERE "Offer"."id" = '1' AND "Offer"."canceled_at" IS NULL
ORDER BY "offer_batches"."name"
ASC LIMIT 12 OFFSET 0;
```

**Environment**

Node: `v14.18.0`

`package.json` dependencies

- pg: `8.7.1`
- pg-hstore: `2.3.4`
- sequelize: `6.9.0`

Trying to find any solution on GitHub issues or stackoverflow, nothing solved this problem. Maybe i'm doing this query wrong, any help would be grateful and welcome :)

Comment: Can you add a generated SQL query for the case `subQuery: false` in main model options and `separate: true` in `Batch` options?

Comment: I could try @Anatoly, you mean like hard coding a raw SQL query in the main model? I was trying to avoid doing this directly on my code to keep pattern of the way i'm building my queries, but it might works.
And stop to thinking now, i think maybe it's better to do in the second way, because the query was getting very nested

Comment: No, just retrieve a SQL query generated by Sequelize while trying to execute the query with these options

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't found a quite solution for this, so i resolved to use `Lazy loading` for this situation instead of `Eager loading`, as mentioned on [Sequelize Docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#fetching-associations---eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading).

I splitted the query into two new queries.

First one, on the "master" model `Offer`, with a simple `findOne()`:

```js
const offer = await Offer.findOne({
  [/* My attributes */],
  where: { /* My conditions */ }
});
```

And a second one, selecting from model `Batch`, without `subQuery: false` option, because is not needed anymore.

```js
const batches = await Batch.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'name',
  ],
  where: { offer_id: offer.id },
  order: [/* My ordenation */],
  include: [
    {
      model: File,
      as: 'gallery',
      attributes: ['id', 'path', 'url'],
    },
  ],
  limit: 12,
  offset: (page - 1) * 12,
});
```